# Resized event does not take effect on inactive tab

Tags: c#, layout

I have a tab control with 2 tabs. In windows_resized event, I resize the elements inside tab 1 according to the window size. 
Everything is fine if I keep tab 1 active. Once I switch to tab 2 and resize the window, and come back to tab 1, the elements in tab 1 are a mess. It seems that the layout code I put to tab 1 does not work. 
I can see from the debugger that the windows_resize event did fire and the layout code did execute on elements inside tab 1.. but I feel like the layout is reset by the default after the windows_resize.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
        Size mainFormSize = ((Control) sender).Size;

        if (m_FormOldSize == mainFormSize)
        {
            return;
        }

        int heightDiff = mainFormSize.Height - m_FormOldSize.Height;
        int widthDiff = mainFormSize.Width - m_FormOldSize.Width;

        int newVerticalMargin = Math.Max(m_OldVerticalMargin + heightDiff / 15, BaseVerticalMargin);

        int heightChange = (heightDiff - (newVerticalMargin - m_OldVerticalMargin)) / 2;
        int widthChange = widthDiff/3;

        m_OldVerticalMargin = newVerticalMargin;


        dgvStrategyList.Height += heightChange;
        dgvTradeSummaries.Height += heightChange;
        dgvStrategyDetails.Height += heightChange;
        dgvTradeAction.Height += heightChange;

        dgvStrategyList.Width += widthChange;
        dgvTradeSummaries.Width += (widthDiff - widthChange);
        dgvStrategyDetails.Width += widthChange;
        dgvTradeAction.Width += (widthDiff - widthChange);

        dgvStrategyList.Location = new Point(dgvStrategyList.Parent.Left, dgvStrategyList.Location.Y);
        dgvStrategyDetails.Location = new Point(dgvStrategyDetails.Parent.Left, dgvStrategyList.Bottom + newVerticalMargin);
        dgvTradeSummaries.Location = new Point(dgvStrategyList.Right + BaseHoriMargin, dgvTradeSummaries.Location.Y);
        dgvTradeAction.Location = new Point(dgvStrategyDetails.Right + BaseHoriMargin, dgvStrategyList.Bottom + newVerticalMargin);

        // adjust labels
        lblStrategyDetails.Location = new Point(dgvStrategyDetails.Location.X, dgvStrategyDetails.Location.Y - lblStrategyDetails.Height - 3);
        lblTradeAction.Location = new Point(dgvTradeAction.Location.X,
            dgvTradeAction.Location.Y - lblTradeAction.Height - 3);
        lblStrategyList.Location = new Point(dgvStrategyList.Location.X, dgvStrategyList.Location.Y - lblStrategyList.Height-3);
        lblTradeSummary.Location = new Point(dgvTradeSummaries.Location.X,
            dgvTradeSummaries.Location.Y - lblTradeSummary.Height - 3);

        m_FormOldSize = mainFormSize;
```

Comment: First, you should be using the ClientSize width and height instead of the form's size property, which includes the caption bar and borders, etc.  If this is happening inside the TabPage, then you should be using that container, not the form. Second, any reason you aren't using Anchors or Dock properties to handle this for you?  Even the TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: @LarsTech since the tab fills the form, I guess it's fine to use form's size. There are 4 datagridviews in the tab, I want them all to resize properly and I can't see how to achieve this using only anchor and dock

Comment: Sounds like a job for the TableLayoutPanel control.  Why do you care about the old size?  The interior size of a TabPage is going to be smaller than the window.  Screen shot might help here since it's unclear why anchors and dockings aren't going to work for you.  I bet they would.

Comment: _since the tab fills the form, I guess it's fine to use form's size_ __No.__ Read the comment again!! - You are right about changing the size of more than two controls, but the calculation really should aim the the real target, __not__ at changes, as Lars says! As while you are at it, resize all DGVs in all tabpages!

Comment: @LarsTech, TableLayoutPanel works, Thanks!